# Embedding videos while hiding the source - is that possible at all?

Tags: video, video-streaming, obfuscation, embedding

Here is the code that I use to embed video from "YouTube" to my blog:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="460" height="390"
data="http://www.youtube.com/v/Hg8Fa_EUQqY&amp;feature&amp;rel=0"><param
name="movie"
value="http://www.youtube.com/v/Hg8Fa_EUQqY&amp;feature&amp;rel=0"
/><param name="wmode" value="transparent" /><param name="quality"
value="high" /></object></p>
```

I wonder if it's possible to embed videos into your blog, but hide the source? I mean I don't want people to know that I have uploaded this video on "YouTube" or at least I don't want them to know where exactly on the "YouTube" I have uploaded my videos.

Is it possible at all?

Embedding videos while hiding the source - is that possible at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If someone is sufficiently motivated, they will always be able to tell where their computer is loading the video from.

But to answer your question, no, the HTML source will always be available to the user. After all, if their browser is allowed to see the source, it will happily provide this to the user. And if the browser isn't allowed to see the source, it can't show the user their video (because it doesn't know there is one, because it didn't see the HTML source).

Comment: I guess the first paragraph of your answer is only true in case of streaming videos, right? Hiding downloading files is still possible, right? Well, at least there is one source here that claims that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764197/a-web-page-that-would-provide-a-user-to-download-a-certain-file-from-it-but-woul

Comment: Anything you send to the user is, at some level, visible to them. This is a fundamental principle of computing.

Comment: Have you looked up the link I gave you in my first comment?

Comment: @brilliant, yes, but the true url is easily detectable by logging HTTP request, and there are any number of tools to do so. In any case, you can't do this with youtube-hosted videos - you have to use their player, and _that_ you cannot hide.

Comment: Can you, please, give me a clue as to what "logging HTTP request" is? Also, you know how sometimes it happens with some browsers like Firefox, a message comes "there are some new updates available" - you click on "Okay" and updates are being downloaded and installed while you have no idea where exactly these new updates are coming from. So, is that also possible somehow to detect where those updates are coming from?

Comment: This is sort of getting off topic from the original question, but basically, the logic goes like this: a) Your computer is downloading it from somewhere. b) Therefore your computer knows where it is. c) You control your computer. d) Therefore you can tell your computer to show you where it's getting it from. As for tools, firefox's web developer toolbar, chrome's http debug page, or just wireshark can get you this kind of info.