# Download Remote File in PHP

Tags: php, download

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Forcing to download a file using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465573/forcing-to-download-a-file-using-php)
>   [PHP - send file to user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882472/php-send-file-to-user)

Is it possible to serve a file from another server , and change the name.
I have all files uploaded in another server but names are changed.I want to hit this server and fetch file from it but want to change it s name.
I wrote a simple curl script , but this adds extra traffic to my php server as well so i will be billed twice for each file and more over it will use php memory as well(if file size increases site may crash)

```
$init   = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($init, $opArray);
$myFile = curl_exec($init);
$info   = curl_getinfo($init); 
curl_close($init);
headers ....
echo File
```

All i am interested is in headers part but for this i need to get file into php server can this be avoided ?

Comment: the process is the same as for any local file. the only difference is that instead of a local file you use a URL instead of a path name. Whether you use cURL or just any of the stream enabled functions is up to you.

Comment: *(reference)* http://php.net/header

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following headers:

```
Content-Type: xxx/xxx
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=theFilenameYouWant.xxx
```

If you want to avoid heavy memory consumption and if you are using Apache as web server, you can take a look at the mod_xsendfile:

http://codeutopia.net/blog/2009/03/06/sending-files-better-apache-mod_xsendfile-and-php/

Comment: x-sendfile does only work with local files, not remote files.