# Write database to CSV file

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP - send file to user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882472/php-send-file-to-user)

I have written a script that successfully outputs userdata to a CSV file on my server.

My question: is there a way to make the CSV file popup so the user can open it? As is, the only way to open the file is directly from the server.

Comment: what do you mean by popup ???

Comment: right.. do you want the user to download the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
    $csv_file = '/path/to/yourfile.csv'; // path to the csv file you're generating on the server

    header('Content-type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($csv_file));

    readfile($csv_file);
?>
```