# Issue sending .docx using php mail()

Tags: php

I am using the following to attach a .docx file to my email to send out.  The issue is, nothing gets sent.  Here is what I am doing:

```
    $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));

    $header = "From: ....";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n"; 

    $filename = "test";
    $file = getcwd() . "/attachments/test.docx";
    $name = basename($file);
    $file_size = filesize($file);
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
    fclose($handle);
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
```

Suggestions, thoughts?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882472/php-send-file-to-user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested and works:

```
<?php

function mail_attachment($filename, $path, $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto, $subject, $message) {
    $file = $path.$filename;
    $file_size = filesize($file);
    $handle = fopen($file, "rb");
    $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
    fclose($handle);
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
    $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
    $name = basename($file);
    $header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
    $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."--";
    if (mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header)) {
        echo "mail send ... OK"; // or use booleans here
    } else {
        echo "mail send ... ERROR!";
    }
}

$file = ""; //File here (eg test.docx)
$path = ""; //Path to file here (eg documents/)
$mailto = ""; //Email address to send to
$from_mail = ""; //Send mail address
$from_name = ""; //From name
$replyto = ""; //Email address to reply to
$subjest = ""; //Mail subject
$message = ""; //Mail body message

mail_attachment($file, $path, $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto, $subjest, $message);

?>
```