# Send a file to user with relevant files included in them

Tags: php, jquery, file-io, simulation

I have been working on this since days. Looks complex or maybe I'm just naive.
I want to render a simulation file to the user on click of a button.

I have used the correct answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882472/php-send-file-to-user), however, there are a many css and js files included in the index.html. And these files do not get loaded when i use readfile().

Since we wanted to validate a logged in user and then render the file, hence we are not serving the file through "*get*" methods or as src from an iframe.

Let me know if more details are needed.
Could someone help me out..in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wait wait...why would readfile() include all of the CSS and JS of another file? Doesn't make sense. Sounds like you're trying to emulate a live website and send over a zip? is that right?

Comment: Im trying to display a simulation to a user. The simulation contains an index in which css and js files are included. If readfile() is not right could you please help me out with the right thing.