# HTML hyperlink with Javascript onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how to make a hyperlink to download the upload file and by the same time it updates its database?

For now I can download the file but it doesn't change the file status.

Here is my code

```
<a href="reports/<?php echo $row['file']; ?>" target="_blank"  onclick="return runMyFunction();">Docx</a> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    Cufon.now(); 
    function runMyFunction() {
        <?php   
             mysql_query("update report_upload set status=1 from report_upload where year='$year' AND area='$area'",$conn);    
        ?>
        return true;
    }   
</script>
```

try1
.html

```
<form id='login' action='adminReportDownload.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                                                            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $area;?>" name="yeara">
                                                            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $year; ?>" name="yeary">
                                                            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $abc123; ?>" name="abc123">
                                                            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Download">
                                                            </form>
```

.php

```
$a = $_POST['yeara'];
$b = $_POST['yeary'];
$c = $_POST['abc123'];
$file_path = 'reports/'.$c;
$sqlABC = "UPDATE report_upload SET status='1', usedBy='$sesId' where year='$b' AND area='$a' ";
$eviABC = mysql_query( $sqlABC, $conn );

header("location: reports/$c");
```

Comment: You can use JavaScript onunload event and make an ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

Because PHP is server-side, it is executed before your browser displays your web page. Thus, your JavaScript function `runMyFunction` contains nothing but a `return true;` statement.

Especially since trying to do server-side operations from the client-side is a bad idea, a better solution may be to have the link point to a PHP page that sends the file and updates the database at the same time.

For further reading, [this question about PHP `readfile`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882472/php-send-file-to-user) may be helpful.

Comment: is it like this? I edit the code, at part try. Although it can update the status, but it can't download it

Comment: @NurfarahadibahShapiee That looks about right. What do you mean by not downloading? Is the header call not redirecting you?

Comment: actually if on hyperlink, when user click on it it will automatically download uploaded file.

Comment: @NurfarahadibahShapiee Does clicking on the link now do everything you need it to do?

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by send post request to server when click on the link.

1. on the eventhandler, prevent the default behavior by `e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation()`
2. write an ajax method to post the request to sever
3. on serverside, update the database, write the file to frontend.

Comment: is it like this? I edit the code, at part try. Although it can update the status, but it can't download it

Comment: you need to modify the response header to `Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"" + "xxx\""`