# PDFs files that can only be accessed by logged-in Joomla Users

Tags: php, .htaccess, pdf, joomla

I have been searching for hours now and it's time to ask you if there's a solution.

I'm trying to make only logged-in Joomla users can see and download my PDFs in a directory.

For this, I created a .htaccess :

```
# Adding PDF compatibility for the control
AddHandler php5-script .pdf
php_value auto_prepend_file "prepend.php"

# Check wether or not user is logged-in
php_value include_path "./journal/"
php_value auto_prepend_file "download.php"
```

I also created a file called "download.php" to check wether or not the Joomla user is loggged-in :

```
<?php
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', '../');
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/framework.php' );

/* Create the Application */
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');

$user = &JFactory::getUser();
if ($user->guest) die();
else {

}
?>
```

And the last file : prepend.php

```
<?php

header('Content-type: application/pdf');
readfile($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']); // serve the requested file
exit(0);

?>
```

Problem is, when I try to access to one of the pdf, I get the plain text version of it. Here's the first lines... And it goes long after.

```
%PDF-1.6 %âãÏÓ 1983 0 obj <>stream hÞì[MoGý+uLÖYŸ‚Fc^†e ÇXŒ¥Ž<°4­ùß/ÉjN„8Y U ìE>oº«Y$«ºÛôà¼ôè DÁ%O2—ß*…¯d¾R}rÙWÙ¡ÏYPq ×ª ƒ bT#ð.d,‚€Q@JAÁ…*v+DFUg$( 3d½ZcG¢Ï^Pu‚Î Ñ³¿=£*6\Il ºAÆ±C1faÆèb z7¹˜A<@¶‘«øÌNÆ’± Y #¶Q•ÃIùØñHÊÇn$¯+±"|!º(^…Ä¨ˆW!;‹x8 ¨ÖBåÐ±Á¥PÅFô.Å(6"0"±Á?SŠb#J¼Øˆl#'±ÙFAa‰l£Žcµˆ5ž–¨ñ§ dFò’@™‘ÀeH2#¡ËÍ?^~š¦Ï¡èN9PPv9ézSaD:£ºœ³Î`%ÈNTnñËl£Å‡ä¿Ì6Zürt¥Å–?.©Òâ—#_®®4ÿ¸KðrX‚VO+1*BWˆ]®×’´"x %«\Ž\Çz—mHé1bU«¸° Ç6¨ˆ§Õ;.Nñ´#nEÇ*žr¹ÊôZdTõZrœwaæsî„ÝàX‹µ2"GŽÍÊ]"{&×ø[”•Û3b¤s‰mPf.òºJÊŒKq\ñ™$På9B©òÞQÊáyŒ$«ÄIæÒ(‚‚£ÄCEFâ=±Ì)K™Ÿ‘Ä8ìT$ƒÄ’¤Rõ.Ûtƒ8I$Ù'–Q»2Øû,†%ÚX£@)xb©ƒÇ(eAIb±ƒI§1^§‘@õ„õ> %±àŠRH–ïsÃÒƒ|‘’”’—ÞÃP¬I Š5*:€ÿây².I&ÿ‘…IæH¬IáV =‚Ô.I‚¨áeñ$¹§à¶)&d­5JRtÜY%LA¬Isb(Ö¤Š5=Ã¨Xº/q`(ÝBEŒ ’h!ªµ(Í:ht¸0,:9¦:' *‚ÄSLº n€,U†I¬Fo¬Z%I¬IU3k”uÿfc² ñ4€šFÐë€"PÓ-m%I/IÆ‚ö7’B QŠ˜d§X¦IèYÉÂ+·‚tãï¾Û¼|ÒÝ½{+¶JÜÜÀùPÀ suÙË®¥@v-b€Á‡Í›íaÚß¦©mw|ñÑµ×ÓÃñåôÅÑæí|=½ÚÞ¶ÍQ½ûr;mÎ‡ûùvžßÏÞ>ßïçãö¸›÷›óéâ¸y~8î~Ý2Ð_?|ÚÃ»OÓtƒÇÍ»íÕa{³y±»º?Lòóz¾ztÿ§ý%3O›×ò×67‘àßïücÚ^Úî¯wûéüÓV\•¯¶‡ùç›íÕlê·†ü â …Š'”N(ŸP9¡zB¤èüzw95{ï8žç‡æÌÏóáóÇyþ¼ùq¾¸¿áˆë•ß½Óp¾¾¿¹{_ÛáB¦ßH@Óp¾”ŽŸ®§›?Vÿt×—ìQKT´îghÀÊ ¢dÀ­å¼²cFcFcFcFcFcFcFcFcFcFcÆŒ9s0æ`Ì¦$9,À˜ƒ1cŽÆ9s4f¢J`ÌÑ˜£1GcNÆœŒ9s2ædÌÉ˜“1'cNÆœŒ9s6ælÌÙ˜³1gcÎÆœ9s6æbÌÅ˜‹1ŸZN1æbÌÅ˜‹1c.Æ\¹³õ99n,À˜«1Wc®Æ\¹3333333333-ÌrºX@Á@4`Ø¤G¾¨ŒÙ4H¦A2 ’iLƒd$Ó ™É4H¦A2 ’iLƒd$Ó ™É4H¦A2 ’iLƒd$Ó ™É4H¦A2 ’iLƒd$Ó ™É4H¦A2 ’iLƒd$Ó ™É4H¦A2 ’iLƒd$Ó ™É4H¦A2 ’iš?<îÒo®ä´Vulú‹ŽíuÞ²ÿqÞ×sž:üS‡êðOþ©Ãÿ:|;bÿ½†­s°cNè˜ÿöœç×ÇoÎåAå,„o™!ý†åyî¯hŽü<¶û¸uÓ³»ãýån>‹) eî§\L‡ùÁ]^Ü–v”Í]ðöz>§ƒÒ7AR‘ç&ø(YÔ’UÖ!kA¯Ý™ï)ØÒs,,=ÇÂ‚G(ðº–îGÓÒ÷eº8l÷ÿ¾ÛÞÜÝï¯ÔƒÔíÁÈ2jÕ–B{¸›¿MÏ~=Ìû£r l»ÿÚM{wùe¿½Ùýç~:C=Z0hË¨~-BeƒÕÜƒ¤ŽÚ½1×ž¹ölÌµgc®=síÙ˜kÏÆ\{úùõ¡×“3uoÊ„CÖõœLÝ½âPçmÖ»ûõTõTu½y'1µ—ÂÃÏÛ;\?üÔ€¾½ÅõÝí |Ùª–÷äq<$Ð˜RÿBzj‡tÍª]³zš€ïš]³úz×÷ÌöBÂz»pn…q•Ó7š‡ýÕyH!,ˆÊz4XBUWüè„Ðz_ÿG @¿JÀ°e×;á!¶€!®HÙº†)Û7+Œ+R¶âÃ´"e«xä~5_N7gKK½Õ®zÑ§ž=<€ûå›^üòmó£¿îÃð["lH ß‰¡3éò5<¿$Çö Äq¦V»!3µ’ yœiù¤Þ_´¡®Ò$ãR0´âcäø \ÎŒãŸ€pùŒû¿1¬ïVBqÅÞ¼<"Ä{s{¯#ß„¾¢¤F9üyS+ÙXûsÙuºNCï Ú¿Ž‚ñÏ?˜Z õ‚´N-§V%iÅZNµQvŸ¶?|ý¿gÀ=ö¿*ôo, endstream endobj 1984 0 obj <>stream hÞŒË1 €0Ð«äéoSmAÜÜ‹õ"ÅEADoov:äÿ^`!8´ä"Aœ§6hKÐ¼ˆF£t‰žºŽÁèÛÈ™Ó¼ðô…óuÞË5leïû?fë˜«cRÇ|k¾ì`TÔN> endstream endobj 1985 0 obj <>stream hÞŒ“KOƒ@€ç§ÌQÊ.°<’¦IcÓ“QR=øˆ´›º ²»4õ'û'ÔÙbÒ‡¹,³0û}Ìpž¤Èó”a»+G.„|ôƒÄAê‚Ã6(ÂÐFí©c±Å$˜ˆmNŠ©»ã3Z¼™ÒÆ¶.†sï:w;—àv÷µôn[¨Ršñ˜Ò¯ª¦´xÁ™7•Æ>—MQxO”„ÙËŽÇ;xY®eéžn$¾²…<[¹1U‰Zš¼Ù\®Íâ|ë:a¸‘Ûöâù[@‹œ*cµzm¬"îd±Rå dÐ‰Ì´\ï*êPBM/od·DÐlö$a¯Ä?%1R¯e£Í ‡èu{Ž¯o˜Ã'CXÀ ”ƒDQ¯(<e IUÓ*Iè”|Ð`â^ø_ãÒ$½šèPsoðN¢5)®(ª¡ Ôº´WïÉfU£KEß×áø9‹Û¬ŽZþüqGødŸåK‰ioƒNaÒcgÄù`D„N
```

Any help will highly be appreciated!

Comment: you probably have a `headers already sent` problem, and your app/pdf header is being ignored/skipped

Comment: There are several third party components did you try any of them? you can find many at http://extensions.joomla.org.

Comment: Well, the only component I found was the "PDF Embed" but it does not do what I wouldlike. I want that in future, people that will be administrating the website will just have to transfer files in the directory and would be downloadable instantly for Users only. This is my only solution I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I finally got this working. As Marc B also mentioned, my **headers** was ignored. I guess the double `php_value auto_prepend_file` didn't work well and the first "prepend.php" was ignored. So I just copy pasted the code and kept everything in one file with the header `Conten-Disposition` added.

Here's the working code :

.htaccess

```
# Adding PDF compatibility to check 
AddHandler php5-script .pdf

#Path of the directory where are stored the PDFs
php_value include_path "./journal/"

#Check wether or not user is logged-in & show pdf if logged-in
php_value auto_prepend_file "prepend.php"
```

prepend.php

```
<?php

/* Loading Joomla User core Files */
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', '../');
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/framework.php' );

/* Create the Application */
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');

/* Check wether Joomla User is logged-in */
$user = &JFactory::getUser();
if ($user->guest) die();
else {

}

/* Sending back pdf */
header("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=myfilename.myextension");
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
readfile($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']); // serve the requested file
exit(0);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this in your PHP code:

```
<?php
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=filename.pdf');
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
readfile($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']); // serve the requested file
exit(0);
```

You can also force it using `.htaccess`:

```
<Files *.pdf>
    Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</Files>
```

Comment: Seems like it doesn't make any changes, and where should I insert the <Files *.pdf>
    Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</Files> ? It gives me an error.

Comment: Well I think I misplaced the <Files *.pdf>
    Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</Files> Should I replace it with AddHandler php5-script .pdf ?

Comment: I think replace is not needed.

Comment: Well it gives me an Internal Server Error. I tried to in all the ways possible and it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

You need additional headers in your response - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2882523/823549 for the full list.

Specifically, `Content-Disposition` will force the save dialog - http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: I tried to add the content-dispositon but it doesn't change the plain pdf I get, and I tried to add the entire content-... in your example and doesn't seems like it changed. I start to think it's getting completly ignored.